# How to assign BIML variable to BIMLScript variable?

Tags: ssis, biml

I have a BIML variable of string type as below

```
<Variable Name="data" Datatype="String" Length="100">hello-world-2018</Variable>
```

I want to assign above BIML variable to C# variable or BIML Script variable in BIML file.

How to get BIML variable value and assign to C# variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made use of **tier** to compile BIML files in required order.

The BIML with lower **tier** value gets compiled first. For each tier objects are added to the RootNode. Higher tiers can use the Objects/Variables from the lower tier.

**FirstFile** : declarebimlvariable.biml

```
<#@ template tier="0" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="Practice">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="data" Datatype="String" Length="100">hello-world-2018</Variable>
            </Variables>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

**SecondFile** : getbimlvariableincsharp.biml

```
<#@ template tier="1" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="Practice2">
            <#
                var data = RootNode.Packages.First(x => x.Name == "Practice").Variables.First(x => x.Name == "data").Value;
            #>
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="<#= data#>">

                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

With usage of tiers and below line worked for me to access BIML variable into C# variable.

```
var data = RootNode.Packages.First(x => x.Name == "Practice").Variables.First(x => x.Name == "data").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use something like

```
<Variable Name="data" Datatype="String" Length="100"><#= myBimlVariable #> </Variable>
```

The `<#=` syntax is is a shorthand in Biml to write the current value of the variable into the xml being built

Comment: I want to access other way round from BIML variable to C# variable.